# null output when flattening nested lists of objects with LINQ select many

Tags: c#, linq, nested

I've got a List of objects that is nested a few levels deep... I'm trying to flatten this list out into a new List of anonymous type... or I can create a new class, it doesn't really matter... I just need to be able to select specific data at various levels of the tree and flatten it out.

The nested structure looks like this:

```
TopResult contains -> List<StepResult> each StepResult contains -> List<PropResult> each PropResult contains -> List<PropBinary>
```

I need to flatten out the nested structure and for some reason when I try to do it with SelectMany, I just keep getting null as my result...
Here's what I'm attempting to do:

```
var resultsModified = results
                .SelectMany(x => (x.StepResults == null ? new List<StepResult>() : x.StepResults)
                .SelectMany(s => (s.PropResults == null ? new List<PropResult>() : s.PropResults)
                .SelectMany(p => (p.PropBinary == null ? new List<PropBinary>() : p.PropBinary)
                .Select(b => new
                {
                    SerialNumber = x.SerialNumber,
                    StationId = x.StationId,
                    StartTime = x.StartTime,
                    ExecutionTime = x.ExecutionTime,
                    Status = x.Status,
                    UserLogin = x.UserLogin,
                    StepName = s == null ? "" : s.StepName,
                    StepType = s == null ? "" : s.StepType,
                    StepOrderNumber = s == null ? null : s.OrderNumber,
                    SequenceName = s == null ? "" : s.SequenceName,
                    StepStatus = s == null ? "" : s.Status,
                    PropName = p == null ? "" : p.Name,
                    PropTypeName = p == null ? "" : p.TypeName,
                    PropTypeValue = p == null ? null : p.TypeValue,
                    PropOrderNumber = p == null ? null : p.OrderNumber,
                    PropCategory = p == null ? null : p.Category,
                    PropData = p == null ? null : p.Data,
                    PropBinaryData = b == null ? null : b.Data
                })))).ToList();
```

All of the lists are initialized as new Lists, and so none of them should ever be null... but I'm doing a null check anyway because I couldn't think of what else to try at this point.

Does anyone have any direction they can point me in as to what I'm missing to get this nested List flattened out?

Comment: a few extension methods would make this code a lot prettier

Comment: I've got a few extensions currently that would clean up all the null checks... Just hadn't pulled in the library where I wrote them.  Any other extension methods you'd recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution that works as I expected.  It's not ideal and is honestly kinda ugly... but this is the only way I could find that did what I needed.

To sum it up, I needed to breakdown each SelectMany into its own statement where I grouped data by the various objects as needed, and from there it's just a series of joins to get the data as expected.

The code:

```
var uutData = results.Select(x => new UutData
            {
                UutResultId = x.Id,
                ...
            }).ToList();

var stepData = results.SelectMany(x => (x.StepResults == null ? new List<StepResult>() : x.StepResults), (x, s) => new StepData
                {
                    UutResultId = x.Id,
                    StepResultId = s.Id,
                    ...
                }).ToList();

var propData = stepData.SelectMany(s => (s.PropResults == null ? new List<PropResult>() : s.PropResults), (s, p) => new PropData
            {
                StepResultId = s.StepResultId,
                PropResultId = p.Id,
                ...
            }).ToList();

//... continue getting nested data objects as needed

var joined = from propStep in (from uutStep in (from uut in uutData
                                             join step in stepData on uut.UutId equals step.UutResultId into step2
                                             from subStep in step2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                             select new
                                             {
                                                 uut.UutSerialNumber,
                                                 ...
                                                 StepName = subStep == null ? "" : subStep.StepName,
                                                 ...
                                                 StepResultId = subStep == null ? "" : subStep.StepResultId
                                             })
                            join prop in propData on uutStep.StepResultId equals prop.StepResultId into prop2
                            from subProp in prop2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select new
                            {
                                uutStep.UutSerialNumber,
                                ...
                                uutStep.StepResultId,
                                PropName = subProp == null ? "" : subProp.PropName,
                                ...
                                PropResultId = subProp == null ? "" : subProp.PropResultId
                            })
                            //... continue joins as needed for all nested objects generated above
                            //appending data from each previous join to carry it all the way through to the final object
                            //to get objects back as List<object>, call .ToList() on entire query (use parentheses to encapsulate entire query)
```

Note that I inserted elipses where I was trying to shorten the code for this answer.  The elipses just need to be replaced with all fields being added to the object.

After all the joins, the final returned List returns a top level object that contains all the relevant data from the nested objects that I needed.  So the data is now no longer nested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have your parenthesis jimmy jacked.  But it manages to still compile.  You want parenthesis like:

```
resultsModified = results
                .SelectMany(x => (x.StepResults == null ? new List<StepResult>() : x.StepResults))  //extra one here
                .SelectMany(s => (s.PropResults == null ? new List<PropResult>() : s.PropResults)) //extra one here
                .SelectMany(p => (p.PropBinary == null ? new List<PropBinary>() : p.PropBinary)) //extra one here
                .Select(b => new
                {
                    SerialNumber = x.SerialNumber,
                    StationId = x.StationId,
                    StartTime = x.StartTime,
                    ExecutionTime = x.ExecutionTime,
                    Status = x.Status,
                    UserLogin = x.UserLogin,
                    StepName = s == null ? "" : s.StepName,
                    StepType = s == null ? "" : s.StepType,
                    StepOrderNumber = s == null ? null : s.OrderNumber,
                    SequenceName = s == null ? "" : s.SequenceName,
                    StepStatus = s == null ? "" : s.Status,
                    PropName = p == null ? "" : p.Name,
                    PropTypeName = p == null ? "" : p.TypeName,
                    PropTypeValue = p == null ? null : p.TypeValue,
                    PropOrderNumber = p == null ? null : p.OrderNumber,
                    PropCategory = p == null ? null : p.Category,
                    PropData = p == null ? null : p.Data,
                    PropBinaryData = b == null ? null : b.Data
                }).ToList(); //remove most of these
```

I think this approach may be a little easier to read though:

```
    var results = list.SelectMany(x => x.StepResults)
                      .Where(x => x != null)
                      .SelectMany(x => x.PropResults)
                      .Where(x => x != null)
                      // etc etc;
```

Comment: Depending what version of C# is allowed, the null propagation `?` and null coalesce `??` operators could clean this a bit. ex: `PropBinaryData = b?.Data` and `StepName = s?.StepName ?? ""`

Comment: So I think I tried this approach and I couldn't access any of the variables except for the last one in the chain, which is why you see the way I was attempting above.  My assumption was that I could only access x,s,p, and b inside of their own selects... And when I tried it in practice I didn't seem to have access to them.  Were you able to compile this code?  Guess I'll give it another shot and report back.

Comment: Yeah, I just tested to verify and this code you posted doesn't work... Variables x, s, and p are not accessible in the call to new